# Parameter packs with specialization for one data type

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, c++17

I have below code to convert all arguments passed to a function into csv:

```
void Parse(ostream& os)
{
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void Parse(ostream& os, T t, Args... args)
{
    os << *t << ',';
    Parse(os, args...);
}
```

While this works fine for all data types for what I am doing, I want some special handling for char data types. If there is a char parameter(for eg. 0) I want to convert it into ascii(48 for zero) and then add it to the csv. I cannot modify it at the caller place. How can I handle it in the parameter pack?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me, what you're asking. Is it `T`=`char` or `T`=`const char*` for which you want special treatment?

Comment: T=char  For eg. a call like Parse(os, myInt, myChar); where myInt is an int and myChar is a char.

Comment: instead of answering in the comments, please clarify your answer by providing a MVCE. Also, if `myInt` is an `int`, your code fails, as it attempts to `os << *myInt << ',';`.

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void Parse(ostream& os, T t, Args... args)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, char>)
    {
        os << to_ascii(t) << ',';
    }
    else
    {
        os << *t << ',';     
    }

    Parse(os, args...);
}
```

Comment: If `T`=`char`, then `*t` makes little sense, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You just define an overloaded function (`details::print()` in the example below) for dealing with a single datum and then join them using a [**fold expression**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
namespace details {

    template<typename T>
    void print(std::ostream&os, T const&x)
    { os << x << ','; }   // print any value

    template<typename T>
    void print(std::ostream&os, T*x)
    { print(os,*x); }     // print value pointed to 

    template<typename T>
    void print(std::ostream&os, const T*x)
    { print(os,*x); }     // print value pointed to 

    void print(std::ostream&os, const char*x)
    { os << x << ','; }   // print C-style string

}

template<typename...Args>
void parse(std::ostream&os, const Args& ...args)
{
    (details::print(os,args) , ...);   // fold expression
}

int main()
{
    double x=3.1415;
    parse(std::cout,"fun",42,'d',&x);
}
```

output: `fun,42,d,3.1415,`

You can suppress the trailing comma by the method of Jarod's answer (though your original post didn't suppress it).

Answer (score 1):

Since you use recursion to handle the parameter pack, you can add two overloads

```
void Parse(ostream& os) {} /* As before. */

void Parse(ostream& os, char *c)
{
    os << handleChar(*c) << ",";
}

template <class T> void Parse(ostream& os, T t)
{
    os << *t << ",";
}
```

and change the original variadic function definition to

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void Parse(ostream& os, T t, Args... args)
{
    Parse(os, t);

    Parse(os, args...);
}
```

The compiler will prefer this non-templated function when calling `Parse` with a two arguments, the second being `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

I would split iteration from real action:

```
template <typename T>
void Handle(std::ostream& os, const char*& sep, T arg)
{
    os << sep << arg;
    sep = ",";
}

void Handle(std::ostream& os, const char*& sep, char arg)
{
    os << sep << (int)arg;
    sep = ",";
}

template <typename... Args>
void Parse(std::ostream& os, Args... args)
{
    const char* sep = "";
    (Handle(os, sep, args), ...);
}
```

Comment: this is essentially the same as my answer (with the addition of suppressing the trailing comma).

Comment: @Walter: Didn't see you answer when I begin to write that (and I did a pause between start and end...)